# How to check if a string matches any of an array of regexes in node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js, lodash

I'm trying to check efficiently if a string matches any of an array of regexes and return true in the first encountered match (Breaking the iteration over the regexes)

My current code:

```
_.forEach(self._connectedClients, function(client) {
        if (client.authenticated) {
            var interested = _.forEach(client.interests, function(interest) {
                if (evt.event_type.search(interest) != -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            if (interested) {
                self._sendJSON(client.socket, data);
            }
        }
    });
```

Interest is an array of regexes.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so, you want to have `var regexes = [/a/,/b/,/c/]` and `var string = "teststring"` and see which regexes match true?

Comment: Wait, is `client.interests` or `interest` an array of regexes?

Comment: @Kristian I don't really care which one matches I just wanna know if any of them matches.
FelixKling The client.interests is the array of regexes.

Comment: Cool, then I'll stick with my answer submission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs#some), when the function passed returns a truthy value iteration will stop and true will be returned. If it can't find a truthy value it will return false, after iterating through the entire array.

Example:

```
_.forEach(self._connectedClients, function(client) {
    if (client.authenticated) {
        if (_.some(client.interests, _.method('test', evt.event_type))) {
            self._sendJSON(client.socket, data);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `.test` is a method on a regular expression, not on a string.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> `some()` executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such an element is found, `some()` immediately returns `true`.

```
var interested = client.interests.some(function(regex) {
  return regex.test(evt.event_type);
});
```

Of course you can also use lodash's `_.some` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, using plain javascript, you could do the following to check for [matches of a single string over multiple regular expressions](http://snipref.com/javascript/javascript-matching-a-string-to-an-array-of-regex-expressions/).

```
for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++) {
  var regex = x[i]; console.log('regex', regex);
  if( str.match( x[i] ) ) {
    console.log("regex:",x[i]," matching: true");
  } else {
    console.log("regex:",x[i]," matching: false");
  }
}
```

However, if you meant something else, then do clarify. :)